# how can i refresh loggedInUser in the main layout in grails, so its photo accepts newly updated photo? I am using acegi plugin for security

Tags: grails, layout, model-view-controller

is there anyway to dynamically refresh grails layout?
example on updating a profile image the image for logged in user does not get updated but it updates on its relative page all right.

photo loads and updated fine in view using userAccountInstance. see below

```
<g:if test="${userAccountInstance?.photoTmp != null  && !(userAccountInstance?.photoTmp.empty)}" >
                  <img id="profile_photo" src="${createLink(controller:'image', action:'thumbnail', id:userAccountInstance.photoTmp)}" alt="${userAccountInstance.photoTmp}" title="${userAccountInstance.photoTmp}" />
                </g:if>
                <g:elseif test="${userAccountInstance?.photo != null  && !(userAccountInstance?.photo.empty)}" >
                  <img id="profile_photo" src="${createLink(controller:'image', action:'thumbnail', id:userAccountInstance.photo)}" alt="${userAccountInstance.photo}" title="${userAccountInstance.photo}" />
                </g:elseif>
```

in main layout doesn't get updated unless user logout and log back in. see below

```
<g:if test="${loggedInUserInfo(field:'photo')}">
                  <img class="thumb_photoo" width="25" height="25" src="${createLink(controller:'image', action:'original', params:[id:loggedInUserInfo(field:'photo'),userId:loggedInUserInfo(field:'id')])}" alt="${loggedInUserInfo(field:'firstname')}" title="${loggedInUserInfo(field:'firstname')}" />
                </g:if>
                <g:else>
                  <img id="profile_photoo" src="${resource(dir:'images', file:'no_image_small_brown.png')}" alt="No Image" height="25"/>
                </g:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling springSecurityService.reauthenticate after your updates in the controller, it has helped me in similar circumstances.

Comment: @wwwclases where do i call springSecurityService.reauthenticate and could you tell the syntax please.